# How can i tell what went wrong on resume from hibernation?

Tags: 11.10, hibernate

I am having trouble with making my VAIO VPCSA2V9R resume after hibernate.

I have a swap, i have updated my grub configuration, initramfs and whatnot, it still won't boot. But at least it tries now - i see a sceen with Ubuntu(r), five white dots and it says 'resuming from ... '.

My question is not why it happens, it is - how can it tell what went wrong? 
Could not find anything relevant in dmesg (mor maybe i don't know to look properly), and /var/log/hibernate doesn't even exist. Where are the logs i should be looking in?

UPDATE:
Thanks Florian!

I hesitated to read these pages before, as I am no kernel developer. But my problem turned out to be a case of encrypted swap  bug, which is described there. I do not have and encrypted swap anymore, but somehow resume thought I did. I removed cryptsetup from my system and it helped. Not a proper solution, but it works. There is probably a proper solution somewhere on this pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume) and [DebuggingKernelSuspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) from the Ubuntu Wiki contain some tips.